# SQL Server, join multiple columns in a row with sum up

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms, multiple-columns

I have rows (about 120000) like this and my table has 3 columns like a, b, c.

```
  a          b          c
 ---        ---        ---
hello      world       10
 hey        you        80
world      hello       20
 my         day        15
merhaba    dunya       40
 life       good       75
good         day       70
thank        you       15
 it          is        40
dunya      merhaba     20
 is          it        80
```

I want to find reverse values in the first two columns (a and b) and sum their values in c column.

The results should look like this:

```
 a          b          c
 ---        ---        ---
hello      world       30
 hey        you        80
  my        day        15
merhaba    dunya       60
 good       day        70
 thank      you        15
  it        is        120
```

Comment: Sum(c) and Group by A and B ?

Comment: If you *really need* a solution, I assume you've tried yourself too. What was your attempt, please do share it as it may (will) help us get you an answer quicker.

Comment: What should happen with multiple rows that have the same (not opposite)  values for A & B?    Like if there were two rows with `A`="Hello" and `B`="World"?

Comment: @Markov yes sir.

Comment: @Larnu i tried it;

select t.a, t.b, sum(t.c + coalesce(t2.c,0))
from mytable t
left join mytable t2 on t.a = t2.b and t.b = t2.a
group by  t.a, t.b

Comment: @TabAlleman I added all to A="Hello" and B="World" rows and i applied this for the all same rows. It's not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
select min(a), max(b), sum(c)
from t
group by (case when a < b then a else b end),
         (case when a < b then b else a end);
```

Comment: Except this result set would include `A`="dunya" and `B`="merhaba" instead of the opposite in the desired result set.   It's not clear in the question how much that matters.